# READ_PHONE_NUMBERS not working below android O

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo, user-permissions, dangerous-permissions

I am requesting this permission READ_PHONE_NUMBERS . On and above 26 is working fine but below 26 the permission dialog to show allow and deny is not popping up. Coded as below .

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[]{android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS}, RC_PN);
```

How can i make it work below android 26(Oreo). ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the code below for different android versions

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, new String[{android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS}, RC_PN);} 
else {
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

More

Requires
`Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` or
`Manifest.permission.READ_SMS` or
`Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS`

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number())

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: getLine1NumberForDisplay: Neither user 10133 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE or android.permission.READ_SMS.

Comment: yeah .. already declared.. Have you tested above code to be working ?

Comment: you meant below O i have to request or READ_PHONE_STATE to get Line1Number ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196039/discussion-between-simplecoder-and-mr-af).

Comment: A.F ... Yeah with little tweak.. it is working.. above 25 used PHONE_NUMBER, below used PHONE_STATE.